# Proving a linear map from a finite dimensional vector space is continuous, without analysis?

Tags: analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

On page 93 in *Introduction to Analysis* by Maxwell Rosenlicht, Problem 22 tasks one with the following:

> Let $V, V'$ be normed vector spaces and $f: V \to V'$ a linear transformation.  Prove the following statements.
>
> (a) If $f$ is continuous at one point it is continuous everywhere, and in fact is uniformly continuous.
>
> (b) $f$ is continuous iff the set $\{ \| f(x)\|/\|x\| : x \in V, x\neq 0 \}$ is bounded.
>
> (c) $f$ is continuous if $V$ is finite dimensional. (*Hint*: Use a basis of $V$.)
>
> (d) The set of all infinite sequences of real numbers with only a finite number of nonzero terms is a normed vector space if we define $$ (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) + (y_1, y_2, y_3, \ldots) = (x_1+y_1, x_2+y_2, x_3 + y_3, \ldots) \\ c(x_1,x_2,x_3,\ldots) = (cx_1, cx_2, cx_3, \ldots) \\ \| (x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)\| = \max \{ |x_1|, |x_2|, |x_3|, \ldots \} $$
>
> and the map sending $(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots)$ into $(x_1, 2x_2, 3x_3, \ldots)$ is a one-one linear transformation of this normed vector space onto itself that is not continuous.

---

I am focusing here on (c) in Problem 22. In short my solution went along the lines of:

> Let $\|\cdot \|$ denote the abstract norm on $V$. Let $\{v_1, \ldots, v_n\}$ be a basis of $V$.
>
> The map $x \mapsto \| x \|$, where $x\in V$, is continuous with respect to the topology induced by the norm $\| \cdot \|_1$
>
> Via compactness, this enables us to conclude there is a real $M > 0$ such that $M \| x \|_1 \leq \| x \| $ for each $x \in V$.
>
> Therefore for any $x \in V$: if $\|x\| < \delta$, then $ \| x \|_1 < \frac {\delta}M $.
>
> Hence we have $\|f(x)\| \leq \sup\{ \| f(v_i) \| \}_{i=1}^n \cdot \| x\|_1 < \sup\{ \| f(v_i) \| \}_{i=1}^n \cdot \frac {\delta}M $, which can be made smaller than any beforehand given $\epsilon > 0$. $\square$

---

But in the subsequent Problem 23, we are tasked with following:

> Use Problem 22 to prove that if $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ and $\| \|_1$, $\| \|_2$ are two norm functions on $V$ (i.e., real-valued functions such that $(V,\| \|_1)$ and $(V, \| \|_2)$ are normed vector spaces), then there exist positive real numbers $m,M$ such that $m \leq \frac { \| x\|_1 }{ \| x\|_2 } \leq M$ for all nonzero $x \in V$.

---

We are asked to use Problem 22 to solve Problem 23. Is this not strange, or am I misunderstanding something?

In order to solve Problem 22 (c), I had to use the property  in Problem 23.

Does this mean Rosenlicht had in mind a different solution of Problem 22 (c)? One *not* invoking the property in Problem 23?

I have been looking online and have not find a proof that does not rely on the property in Problem 23, namely the equivalence of norms in finite dimensional vector spaces.

Does anyone know if Problem 22 (c) can be solved without invoking equivalence of norms? Thank you.

Comment: You can prove that a linear operator is bounded on finite dimensional Hilbert space, and it is continuous if it is bounded.

Comment: Regarding to your confusion, you *do not* need Problem 22 (c) to prove Problem 23. However, it is clear that the author's intention is to let the readers prove Problem 22 (c) without the knowledge of Problem 23.

Comment: @Tab1e thank you for your input! in this case all we know is that $V$ is endowed with a norm; we have no access to a inner product. what I am struggling to see is how we can prove problem 22 (c) without the knowledge of problem 23. evidently I used problem 23 to solve (c) in 22. is there a way to do it without the property in problem 23? i.e. can we forego analysis to solve (c)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\text{dim}(X) = n$ and there is a basis $\{e_1, \dots, e_n\}$ for $X$. We can write $x = \sum \zeta_i e_i$ and derive
$$
\begin{align*}
\|f(x)\|_Y =\left\|\sum\zeta_if(e_i)\right\|_Y &\leq \sum |\zeta_i|\|f(e_i)\|_Y \\
&\leq \max_k \|f(e_k)\|_Y \sum|\zeta_i|
\end{align*}
$$
Try to prove the following lemma:

**Lemma**

> Let $\{x_1, \dots, x_n\}$ be a linearly independent set of vectors in
> a normed space $X$. Then there is a number $c >0$ such that for every
> choice of scalars $\alpha_1,\dots, \alpha_n$ we have
> $$
> \|\alpha_1 x_1 + \dots + \alpha_n x_n\| \geq c(|\alpha_1|+\dots+|\alpha_n|)
> $$

Using the lemma, we have
$$
\sum |\zeta_i| \leq \frac1c \left\|\sum\zeta_ie_i\right\|_X = \frac1c \|x\|_X
$$
for some $c>0$. Now you have
$$
\|f(x)\|_Y \leq \alpha\|x\|_X
$$
where $\alpha = \frac1c \max_k \|f(e_k)\|_Y$.

From this, you can try to prove that $f$ is continuous if it is bounded.

Comment: "Derive (try to prove this)", but this property is exactly that of Problem 23, no? The crux here is that Problem 22 precedes Problem 23. This leads me to suspect there ought to be a way to do it without adverting to the property in Problem 23.

Comment: @kapython NO. This property is not equivalent to the equivalence of norm. Only one norm is used in the statement, how did you come up with that conclusion?

Comment: @kapython I have rephrased the property as a lemma.

Comment: Tab1e:  my impulse to attribute problem 23 to the lemma was due to it invoking a relationship between the abstract norm $\|\cdot \|_X$ and $\|\cdot \|_1$, but this was perhaps wrongful.

Comment: Tab1e: To show it, we know $x \mapsto \|x\|_X$ is continuous under the topology induced by $\|\cdot \|_1$. Then we consider this map on the compact set $\{x\in V : \|x\|_1=1\}$ and argue existence of a positive minimum value.